# Aplicativo Android funciona no emulador, mas não no aparelho físico

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

Todo o projeto, inclusive o *back-end* funciona perfeitamente quando executado no emulador do *Android* no *Visual Studio*, mas quando gero o arquivo `APK` em modo `release` e executo no meu *smartphone*, somente o *front-end* funciona, já o *back-end* não funciona.

Eu sinceramente não sei onde está o problema, alguém pode me apontar uma solução?

Comment: Teria que dar mais detalhes/informações dobre o `backend`. Como está a configuração? é um `web service`? Esta na internet ou na rede local?

Comment: No momento local, é um chat feito com a tecnologia rabbitMQ, o visual studio instalou perfeitamente as referências, e permitiu a utilização no projeto, e funciona perfeitamente nos emuladores Android.

Comment: Não haveria nenhuma dependências de outros pacotes para o `rabbitMQ` funcionar no Android? Sou leigo no assunto, pois quando não faço em Javascript crio nativ para Windows Phone, e ás vezes acontece de ter de instalar algumas dependências no aparelho.

Comment: Normalmente se o rabbitMQ necessita de algo mais ele exibe erros no console do Visual Studio... Como por exemplo, quando vai fazer a instalação do rabbitMQ no portable do xamarin.form, ele não permite. Sinceramente, é algo interessante, somente o front-end funciona.